# Install on ubuntu fails

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ejabberd

Using... apt-get -y install ejabberd

I get during the install

```
 Process: 21311 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl start && /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl started (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 21.400s

Mar 19 14:07:14 webserver-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start A distributed, fault-tolerant Jabber/XMPP server.
Mar 19 14:07:14 webserver-1 systemd[1]: ejabberd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 19 14:07:14 webserver-1 systemd[1]: ejabberd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I can't enter the directory to edit the config no permission

drwxr-x---   3 root  ejabberd  4096 Mar 19 14:05 ejabberd

What am I doing wrong? I've uninstall and reinstalled a few times and get the same result.

Yani

Comment: try this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu

Comment: That's the tutorial I've been using.

The only difference is the first time I did the install I used a different tutorial and did the install from Git, a far more manual process.

It looks to me like it's set up its own user. Hence I can't edit the config files.

Comment: Did you try installing the version packaged by ejabberd dev team?  https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/